# Is there a popular Linux/Unix format for binary diffs?

Tags: linux, gzip, diff, binaryfiles, delta

I'm going to be producing binary deltas of multi-gigabyte files.

Naively, I'm intending to use the following format:

```
struct chunk {
    uint64_t offset;
    uint64_t length;
    uint8_t data[];
};

struct delta {
    uint8_t file_a_checksum[32]; // These are calculated while the
    uint8_t file_b_checksum[32]; // gzipped chunks are being written
    uint8_t chunks_checksum[32]; // at the 96 octet offset.
    uint8_t gzipped_chunks[];
};
```

I only need to apply these deltas to the original `file_a` that was used to generate a delta.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Is there an existing binary delta format which has the features I'm looking for, yet isn't too much more complex?

Comment: [VCDIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCDIFF)?

Comment: Thanks, but this may be overkill as 99% of data is unchanged and it never moves location within the file.

Comment: That's likely going to be the case with any existing binary delta format: if it's a general purpose format, it won't be optimised for your particular use case. And if it's a highly specific format, you're going to need a bit of luck for someone with experience with it to see your question.

Comment: See http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arbitrary binaries, of course it makes sense to use a general purpose tool:

- xdelta
- bspatch
- rdiff-backup (rsync)
- git diff

(Yes, `git diff` works on files that aren't under version control. `git diff --binary --no-index dir1/file.bin dir2/file.bin` )

I would usually recommend a generic tool before writing your own, even if there is a little overhead. While none of the tools in the above list produce binary diffs in a format quite as ubiquitous as the "unified diff" format, they are all "close to" standard tools.

There is one other fairly standardised format that might be relevant for you: the humble hexdump. The `xxd` tool dumps binaries into a fairly standard text format by default:

```
0000050: 2020 2020 5858 4428 3129 0a0a 0a0a 4e08      XXD(1)....N.
```

That is, offset followed by a series of byte values. The exact format is flexible and configurable with command-line switches.

However, `xxd` can also be used in reverse mode to *write* those bytes instead of dumping them.

So if you have a file called `patch.hexdump`:

```
00000aa: bbccdd
```

Then running `xxd -r patch.hexdump my.binary` will modify the file `my.binary` to modify three bytes at offset `0xaa`.

Finally, I should also mention that `dd` can seek into a binary file and read/write a given number of bytes, so I guess you could use "shell script with `dd` commands" as your patch format.